# I get an error when trying to extend a widget, why?

Tags: jquery, widget

Here are two widgets.

http://pastebin.com/kheULT7h

If I try and extend 'sb.textboxesApp' from 'sb.baseApp' I get an error:

"TypeError: s is not a constructor"

But why???

Isn't that how you extend a widget?

jquery 1.8.3
jquery ui 1.10.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're supposed to pass the widget itself as the second argument of .widget(). Not a string. Here is my test. http://jsfiddle.net/ho873kz4/

```
/****************************

Base Widget

        Requires jQuery
        Requires jQuery UI

****************************/

(function($, undefined) {
        'use_strict';



        /*
        * A widget.
        */
        $.widget('sb.baseApp', {
                /*
                * Widget Option
                */
                options: {},



                /*
                * Constructor, called once when first created
                */
                _create: function() {
                    console.log('baseApp created');
                },

                /*
                * Initialisation, called after _create and and on later widget calls.
                */
                _init: function() {
                },

                /*
                * Destructor, cleanup when no longer needed.
                */
                _destroy: function() {
                }
        });
} (jQuery));



/****************************

Textbox Widget

        Requires jQuery
        Requires jQuery UI

****************************/

(function($, undefined) {
        'use_strict';



        /*
        * A widget
        */
        $.widget('sb.textboxesApp', $.sb.baseApp, {
                /*
                * Widget Option
                */
                options: {},



                /*
                * Constructor, called once when first created
                */
                _create: function() {
                    console.log('textboxesApp create');
                    return this._super();
                },

                /*
                * Initialisation, called after _create and and on later widget calls.
                */
                _init: function() {
                },

                /*
                * Destructor, cleanup when no longer needed.
                */
                _destroy: function() {
                }
        });
} (jQuery));

jQuery.sb.textboxesApp();
```